# Cryptic Family Reunion: String of Pearls

Tags: cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". **NOTE:** Unlike many previous puzzles in this genre, clues are NOT sorted alphabetically; however, lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Mom, racy without seeming forward, to can-can with Auntie (10)
2. Sister to dance Brazilian-style, discarding midriff (4)
3. Ma's retort harsh, biting head off niece and nephew (10)
4. Son mimics giant iguana camouflage (7)
5. Dad invested in Hess forward ahead of Saipan oil venture (10)
6. Uncle to obtain legal advice, tips after criminal act (7)
7. Romantic goodbye (throwing THAT is "face down") after cutting affront to sister (8)
8. Romantic goodbye (throwing THAT is "face down") after cutting affront to sister (7)
9. Brother shattered our rice pot (6,4)
10. Grandpa's direction is to seize leader of violence (5)

Solver Note: I realize the surface of the Schrödinger clue seems a little off, but 1. it's a Schrödinger clue, cut me some slack :-) and 2. there actually is a definition on Urban Dictionary that makes the surface more sensible if significantly less wholesome. I recommend you just take my word for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1   Mom, racy without seeming forward, to can-can with Auntie (10)
```

> MARTINIQUE (Mom (MA) + racy (RISQUE) - first letter of seeming (S) + can (TIN)) — thanks to @Stiv for this

```
2   Sister to dance Brazilian-style, discarding midriff (4)
```

> SABA (samba - middle letter M)

```
3   Ma's retort harsh, biting head off niece and nephew (10)
```

> MONTSERRAT (Ma’s retort, anagrammed + N(iece)) — thanks to @Stiv for this one!

```
4   Son mimics giant iguana camouflage (7)
```

> ANTIGUA (in giANT IGUAna)

```
5   Dad invested in Hess forward ahead of Saipan oil venture (10)
```

> HISPANIOLA (H + (Saipan oil) anagrammed)

```
6   Uncle to obtain legal advice, tips after criminal act (7)
```

> TORTOLA (criminal act TORT + tips of Obtain Legal Advice

```
7   Romantic goodbye (throwing THAT is "face down") after cutting affront to sister (8)
```

> BARBADOS (cutting affront is a BARB + Romantic goodbye (ie. Spanish is a Romance language) ADIOS - the face of is (I))

```
8   Romantic goodbye (throwing THAT is "face down") after cutting affront to sister (7)
```

> BARBUDA (cutting affront is a BARB + Romantic goodbye (ie. French is a Romance language) AD(-ie)U backwards (ie. face down)) — thanks to @Stiv for this

```
9   Brother shattered our rice pot (6,4)
```

> PUERTO RICO (our rice pot, anagrammed)

```
10  Grandpa's direction is to seize leader of violence (5)
```

> NEVIS (NE is a direction + IS, and seizing V, leader of violence)

These are all

> CARIBBEAN ISLANDS, which can be known as pearls of the sea

Comment: Gagh, you were just ahead of me, with a similar number solved. 3 is incorrect because rot13(ZNEGVAVDHR vf 1 - ZN + EV(-f)DHR + GVA)

Comment: And in fact, 3 is rot13(ZBAGFREENG = ZNFERGBEG* + A(vrpr))

Comment: And 8 is rot13(ONEOHQN = ONEO + NQ(-vr)H nyy nantenzzrq)

Comment: Good pickups, @Stiv! I knew my #3 had to be 1 of them, I just couldn’t completely parse it. Thanks — credit forthcoming

Comment: El-Guest and @Stiv: Well you guys crushed that one! Can you please do me a favor and really give the Schrödinger clue a thorough explanation? I'm not sure either is quite right yet. I worked really hard to get the wordplay to work up to Deusovi standards (not sure I got there :-)

Comment: @JeremyDover — how does this look for the Schrodinger clue explanation? Is there another answer too that you’re looking for, or another clueing for the same answer?

Comment: The answers to #7 and #8 are correct, and the intended ones. In #7: just hoping for a little more explanation re: the use of rot13(Ebznagvp) and how to get the rot13(- V) from rot13(guebjvat GUNG vf "snpr qbja"). Also #8 is not rot13(nantenzzrq) (@Stiv for awareness). The needed transformation is clued.

Comment: @JeremyDover Ah yes, a slip of the keyboard there. 'Face down' is obviously the key there...

Comment: Lots of fun as always, @JeremyDover!